# NLP Entity Recognition Inquiry

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy, rasa-nlu

I am working on an NLP Chatbot project. The Chatbot will need to process requests like the following:

"I want to go to Penn Station from Back Bay Station" and "I want to go from Back Bay Station to Penn Station"

In each case, I want to extract the source train station as "Back Bay Station" and the destination as "Penn Station." However, because of the sentence re-ordering, I am not sure how to do this.

Any advice, including examples, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.

1. Heuristics: Look for words like 'to' and 'from' and similar before the entities. You might have to spend some time creating a library of these prepositions or subordinating conjunctions but that will do the job.
2. Use more sophisticated [deep parsers](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) that can do this job for you. You might have to still fall back to heuristics here as well, but you can get much more information this way. I am suggesting this option because I don't know how wide your problem statement is. If it is just about 'to' and 'from' then stick to option 1